# PHP Warning: ftp_get(): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, ftp, permission-denied

I have a problem with my `ftp_get()` and it really makes me confused.

I work on a local development (right now) and my FTP server is on my own computer. I want to upload/download files using FTP. I have yet managed to upload files with `ftp_put()`, it's ok. Now for downloading, I can change to the right directory of my FTP server, I can list the files via `ftp_nlist()`, it's OK for that, but when I do `ftp_get()`, my Apache log says me for `[client 127.0.0.1]`:

```
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/public_html/myfile.txt on line 62
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Error opening myfile.txt in /var/www/public_html/myfile.txt on line 62
```

Line 62 is where I do my `ftp_get`, like this:

`ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)`

I've done a lot of searches and answers are always like "beware of the owner" or "beware of the chmod" but I can't figure out what really is the thing I need to do. The owner of the root directory of the FTP server is the same as the owner of the file I try to download. So I don't know what to do, I think there is something confused in my mind.

Comment: Hi, I just have solved my probleme adding " /tmp/ " to my $local_file. now it works perfectly, no more "Permission denied". I don't know why exactly but good!
If it can help somebody.

Comment: The second parameter of the ftp_get function specifies the local path where you want to download the remote file to.

Previously you were downloading the file to /var/www/public_html/ where probably you don't have permissions to create files. When you add /tmp/ to the $local_file path you are specifying the system /tmp folder which has the appropriate permissions