# Downloading file from ftp in codeigniter 2 using FTP Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to download some file from FTP Server using FTP Class that already in CodeIgniter, but i get error ftp_get() failed to open stream : permission denied when i called my code. anyone can help me, please ?

this is my code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_FTP extends CI_Controller 
{
public function openfile($fileName)
{
    $this->load->library('ftp');
    $config['hostname'] = 'ftp_host';
    $config['username'] = 'ftp_username';
    $config['password'] = 'ftp_password';
    $config['port']     = 'ftp_port';
    $config['debug']    = FALSE;
    $config['passive']  = FALSE;
    $this->ftp->connect($config);
    $this->ftp->download('path/to/folder/', 'local/path', 'auto');
    $this->ftp->close();
}}
?>
```

and my ci version is : 2.2.0

Comment: First thing you need to do when you get a 500 error is check the PHP error log, then you can find out the real error message.

Comment: Thank you in advance, now i found the real error, and error is `failed to open stream: permission denied`, i have followed step in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811103/php-warning-ftp-get-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied) but doen't work.

i get the difference error : `The system cannot find the file specified` when i change my local path to `/tmp`, i think this folder existing only in linux but i use windows

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution of my problem, just add header before you download the file
this my code :

before

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_FTP extends CI_Controller 
{
public function openfile($fileName)
{
    $this->load->library('ftp');
    $config['hostname'] = 'ftp_host';
    $config['username'] = 'ftp_username';
    $config['password'] = 'ftp_password';
    $config['port']     = 'ftp_port';
    $config['debug']    = FALSE;
    $config['passive']  = FALSE;
    $this->ftp->connect($config);
    $this->ftp->download('path/to/folder/', 'local/path', 'auto');
    $this->ftp->close();
}}
?>
```

change with this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_FTP extends CI_Controller 
{
public function openfile($fileName)
{
    $this->load->library('ftp');
    $config['hostname'] = 'ftp_host';
    $config['username'] = 'ftp_username';
    $config['password'] = 'ftp_password';
    $config['port']     = 'ftp_port';
    $config['debug']    = FALSE;
    $config['passive']  = FALSE;
    $this->ftp->connect($config);
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
    $this->ftp->download('path/to/folder/', 'local/path', 'auto');
    $this->ftp->close();
}}
?>
```